# Namespaces not properly working after using php-scoper

Tags: php, google-analytics, namespaces, google-analytics-api

My plugin was having conflict with the other plugin if it was using google library in Wordpress. Previously my vendor folder was namespace by prefix Analytify using php-scoper excluding the namespaces **Composer, Grpc and Google** I worked around the solution and then I exclude three more namespaces that were **Guzzlehttp, Monology, and Psr** and by this the conflict was totally resolved.
But now I was making the entire vendor namespace to MyPlugin so that it is totally containerized but then I get following errors in my plugin and I have looked into them and all the mentioned classes are properly namespace by MyPlugin but it is saying not found. The errors are:

> WARNING MyPlugin\Google\Analytics\Admin\V1alpha\DataStream is not found in descriptor pool. Only generated classes may derive from Message

> WARNING MyPlugin\Google\Analytics\Admin\V1alpha\ListDataStreamsRequest is not found in descriptor pool

> WARNING (query) missing required param: 'siteUrl'

> WARNING MyPlugin\Google\Analytics\Admin\V1alpha\ListAccountsRequest is not found in descriptor pool

> WARNING MyPlugin\Google\Analytics\Admin\V1alpha\ListAccountsRequest is not found in descriptor pool

Now I want a way to solve this because I have checked the classes are namespace properly but it is showing not found. Any clue to fix it?

My scoper.inc.php file is

```
<?php

declare (strict_types=1);
namespace MyPlugin;

// scoper.inc.php
use MyPlugin\Isolated\Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;
return [
    'prefix' => 'MyPlugin',
    // string|null
    'output-dir' => null,
    // string|null
    'finders' => [],
    // list<Finder>
    'patchers' => [],
    // list<callable(string $filePath, string $prefix, string $contents): string>
    'exclude-files' => [],
    // list<string>
    'exclude-namespaces' => [],
    // list<string|regex>
    'exclude-constants' => [],
    // list<string|regex>
    'exclude-classes' => [],
    // list<string|regex>
    'exclude-functions' => [],
    // list<string|regex>
    'expose-global-constants' => \false,
    // bool
    'expose-global-classes' => \false,
    // bool
    'expose-global-functions' => \false,
    // bool
    'expose-namespaces' => [],
    // list<string|regex>
    'expose-constants' => [],
    // list<string|regex>
    'expose-classes' => [],
    // list<string|regex>
    'expose-functions' => [],
];
```

Also a guidance needed that is excluding the namespaces on which error occurs is better or just namespace entire vendor that contains Google Libraries for php